# Jquery dataTable handle json data with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

First, I have data from url like this  `GET /api/fruit?per_page=10&page=1` and this is what I got :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Orange",
      "price": "200"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Manggo",
      "price": "300"
    },
    ...(display 10 data)
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "total": 69487,
      "count": 10,
      "per_page": 10,
      "current_page": 1,
      "total_pages": 4633
    }
  }
}
```

Then I following this code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RM3W2/5/) and success render data, and pagination work as well. But input search not working. My question is how to use jquery dataTable properly with data from api like this `GET /api/fruit?per_page=10&page=1`

Comment: Please help me :'(